# Spring oauth2 login - Google/Facebook working but also need basic form-based auth

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have my Spring project up-and-running with Google/Facebook login working fine.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

If I just want form-based login (i.e. username/password, no oauth), I do the following:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/private").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/accounts/**").hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN,Role.MANAGER,Role.USER)
            .antMatchers("/books/**").hasAnyRole(Role.MANAGER,Role.USER)
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .logout()
             .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
             .clearAuthentication(true)
             .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
             .logoutSuccessUrl("/loggedOut").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
             .invalidateHttpSession(true)
             .permitAll()
    }
}
```

Form-based login also works fine.

But how to combine the two? i.e. user can login with either their username/password pair or their social media account?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "combine the two"? It looks like something more layout design than a back-end question.

Comment: @AntonioSaco I'm not really that concerned about the front-end, it's more how to get the `HttpSecurity http` cascade working? There's `.and()` but there's no `.or()`... I should my form based basic login generate a valid oauth2 token?

Comment: @AntonioSaco My goal is a login page with username/password and optional social login... I use React.js on the front-end

Comment: Understand, there is a good reason for not have an "or" and is because you really "add" functionality to the security chain.

Comment: @AntonioSaco more interesting insight. Thank you. I think if I explicitly specify the paths "login_form" and "login_oauth" `.and()` should make sense...

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you need to add to your sequence, is: when a user logged in through social login, you have to **"exchange" that authentication with your own** (a valid session), so you can process your configuration like you do for Form-based login (also, no need to issue an access_token).

Best!

Comment: Mmm. That could be the thing to do! Exchange oauth2 for a basic auth (i.e. JSESSIONID session)? I was thinking of exchanging the JSESSIONID for an oauth2 token... Interesting...